# Using printf to Print Columns

Tags: java, printf

I want to print columns using the formatting specifier with printf in Java. However I can't seem to get this right. I want the numbers to be aligned perfectly.

**This is what I want to get:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrK4A.png)

**This is what I am getting:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o229g.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabTimeTable{

   public static void main(String [] args){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Time Table:");

   System.out.print("Number (1-10): ");
   int number1 = input.nextInt();
   int number2 = (number1+1);

      for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){

         System.out.printf("%2d * %d = %d", i, number1, (number1*i));
         System.out.printf("%12d * %3d = %d", i, number2, (number2*i));
         System.out.println();

      }


   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use something like this:

```
System.out.printf("%2d * %d = %-10d", i, number1, (number1*i));
System.out.printf("%d * %3d = %d", i, number2, (number2*i));
System.out.println();
```

Here I am using *-**10d***, which allocates 10 letter spaces for the last number in the first column, it includes the number too.
Also notice, I removed **12d** from second column, because it will make even greater space between these two columns.